# PYTHON CODE : why the time difference between these codes

Tags: python, python-3.x, timeit

ar=Array of 3000 random numbers,
len(ar), length of array,
Why this code is faster:

```
def tst5()
start=timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(1,len(ar)):
    a=ar[i]
    for j in range((i-1),-1,-1):
        if (a<ar[j]):
            ar[j+1]=ar[j]
            ar[j]=a
        else:
            break
stop=timeit.default_timer()
print(stop-start)
```

then, below mension code:

```
def tst5():
start=timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(1,len(ar)):
    a=ar[i]
    for j in range((i-1),-1,-1):
        if (a<ar[j]):
            ar[j+1]=ar[j]
        else:
            break
        ar[j]=a
stop=timeit.default_timer()
print(stop-start)
```

code number 2 should be faster as it writes less variable 'a' into array then code number 1,
after taking average of 5 times of each functions with new random numbers each time
and then taking average of 10 times of each functions with new random numbers each time,
still it results in code 1 to faster then code 2?

Comment: Are you forgetting the `ar[j]=a` after break in second code.

Comment: ar[j]=a is written in if statement in code1, thats why it should take more time but on the contrary it takes less time, and code 2 is taking more time

Comment: How *much* faster? Are you sure the difference is repeatable and significant?

Comment: for computations 10 times, it averages for 5-7% faster,

Comment: In both cases, `ar[j] = a` is executed the same number of times, when `a < ar[j]` is true.

Comment: yes, ar[j]=a executes same number of times, still there is difference of 5-7% of time.

Comment: The byte code generated by the two is nearly the same, modulo the swapping of two blocks. Maybe there's something in the byte code evaluator that can take advantage of the difference.

Comment: While I can't explain the difference, there's no more reason to believe code 2 should be faster than code 1 than vice versa.

Comment: i think i agree with you. thanks

Comment: This is good material for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks , i am naive user for stack overflow and stack exchange,